# How to apply multithread function in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I want to use multithread function in optaplaner.

I edited cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml
and set multithread count 4

but I think it does not work.
All thread name is the same.

19:37:12.980 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1533), time spent (5839), score (-3266init/0hard/-909220soft), selected move count (1276), picked move (CloudProcess-1262 {null -> CloudComputer-1112}).
19:37:12.982 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1534), time spent (5841), score (-3265init/0hard/-909710soft), selected move count (1600), picked move (CloudProcess-1053 {null -> CloudComputer-908}).
19:37:12.984 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1535), time spent (5843), score (-3264init/0hard/-909710soft), selected move count (1277), picked move (CloudProcess-1049 {null -> CloudComputer-1138}).
19:37:12.987 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1536), time spent (5846), score (-3263init/0hard/-912110soft), selected move count (1600), picked move (CloudProcess-1003 {null -> CloudComputer-1231}).
19:37:12.990 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1537), time spent (5849), score (-3262init/0hard/-912110soft), selected move count (1278), picked move (CloudProcess-941 {null -> CloudComputer-1231}).
19:37:12.992 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1538), time spent (5851), score (-3261init/0hard/-912110soft), selected move count (1278), picked move (CloudProcess-893 {null -> CloudComputer-1231}).
19:37:12.994 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1539), time spent (5853), score (-3260init/0hard/-914510soft), selected move count (1600), picked move (CloudProcess-840 {null -> CloudComputer-1286}).
19:37:12.996 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1540), time spent (5855), score (-3259init/0hard/-916910soft), selected move count (1600), picked move (CloudProcess-820 {null -> CloudComputer-1311}).
19:37:12.998 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1541), time spent (5857), score (-3258init/0hard/-916910soft), selected move count (1278), picked move (CloudProcess-779 {null -> CloudComputer-1231}).
19:37:13.000 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1542), time spent (5859), score (-3257init/0hard/-916910soft), selected move count (1279), picked move (CloudProcess-768 {null -> CloudComputer-1286}).
19:37:13.003 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1543), time spent (5862), score (-3256init/0hard/-917470soft), selected move count (1600), picked move (CloudProcess-739 {null -> CloudComputer-750}).
19:37:13.005 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1544), time spent (5864), score (-3255init/0hard/-917470soft), selected move count (1278), picked move (CloudProcess-728 {null -> CloudComputer-1231}).
19:37:13.007 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1545), time spent (5866), score (-3254init/0hard/-917470soft), selected move count (1278), picked move (CloudProcess-671 {null -> CloudComputer-1231}).
19:37:13.009 [l-4-thread-1] DEBUG     CH step (1546), time spent (5868), score (-3253init/0hard/-917470soft), selected move count (1279), picked move (CloudProcess-615 {null -> CloudComputer-1286}).

I checked rebased implementation in cloudChangeMove, couldSwapMove.
It was already implemented like belows.

```
@Override
public CloudComputerChangeMove rebase(ScoreDirector<CloudBalance> destinationScoreDirector) {
    return new CloudComputerChangeMove(destinationScoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(cloudProcess),
            destinationScoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(toCloudComputer));
}
```

Did I forget something?
The version of optaplaner is 7.23.

But it was the same previous version(7.22)

Please let me know my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `TRACE` logging. The steps are done by the solver thread, the move evaluations (only visible in trace logging) are done by the move threads.